What ratio in grams makes a "complete protein" when combining lentils and rice?
What ratio of rice is needed for lentils to be a "complete protein"?
I realize this was asked before, but I insist it was never answered. I am biased because I had the same question, but within 2 seconds I saw the moderator's answered missed the actual question.
Not only is ratio relevant - it IS the question. The question wasn't about nutritional advice or dietary statistics. There are x amount of essential amino acids and y amount of those cannot be converted by the human body. It is implied by putting "complete protein" in quotes that the question is referring to this aforementioned fact.
If rice contains n grams of protein, "k", per m grams of rice and lentils contain j grams of protein "l" (a "complete" compliment to "k"), then what is the ratio of lentils to rice that makes a complete protein?
The point was to be able to find someone else asking the same question and not have to do the research ourselves. If no one can answer, I guess I'll just do the research and answer my own question so that others asking the same question can find this answer.
sidebar: perhaps irrelevant now that LLM search bots are freely available. I wonder if a predictor of words can appear to ascertain the meaning of the question within a few seconds as well.

Nope, even gemini could not answer this.

What makes it complicated is that there are 9 essential amino acids, there is variability in each of the ingredients of question, and the answer could be different from the perspective of adding rice to lentils, lentils to rice, or if you are trying to maintain some ratio of carbs to protein or protein per meal - The latter of which was never part of the question, but always gets included in answers which is why LLMs also always include it ( because it is just a language predictor fed by the internet - it is not generalized AI ).

Lets pretend 1. There are only 3 essential amino acids (which is where all proteins come from): MAJORine, LENTILine, & RICEine. 2. Rice contains 1g of RICEine and 1g of MAJORine per kg and Lentils contain 200g of MAJORine and 100g LENTILine per kg.

In this scenario - A. Adding lentils to rice to make a complete protein: 0.01 : 1 - B. Adding rice to lentils to make a complete protein 1: 0.001 - C. It does not matter that rice isn't sufficient for your daily dietary recommended protein intake. All that matters pertaining to the question is that all 3 are present. It took 2 seconds to see that was what the original question was asking. Now answer with there being 9 essential amino acids and that there is variability in content in both lentils and rice around the world.

Lentils contain all essential amino acids in some quantity. So I guess the ratio you’re looking for is “1:0”. Though I have no idea what kind of a distinction you’re trying to draw between “adding rice to lentils” and “adding lentils to rice”… your body doesn’t know which one was on top.

@Sneftel it’s basically a minimization problem - minimum combined calories to achieve the sufficient amount of amino acids. Or, which ratio of rice:lentil gets closest to the “ideal” ratio for the least amount of calories. And sure you can just eat more and people have different total needs, but once you have the ratios they would scale easily

Okaaaay…. So how does that fit with the OP’s contention that the ideal ratio of rice to lentils is not the reciprocal of the ideal ratio of lentils to rice? And how is any of this meant to not be a matter of nutrition?

Nice @fyrepenguin. Exactly. But I too would like to know how well it would scale. But the question must be answered first.

@Sneftel  The inverse reciprocals were just an artifact of a simple example I would guess since it gets more complicated with there being 9 actual essential amino acids. I think rice primarily lacks in one of them (besides not being very high protein overall). It is a matter of nutrition ultimately, but we ask one question at a time to get there. Presumption about the larger nutritional questions will just get in the way of the original question. Who knows why they asked it. Can you answer it?

Lentils are "deficient" in the sulfur-containing essential amino acids methionine and cysteine. Rice contains "sufficient" amounts of these. This is why lentils and rice are such a great combination throughout ancient history. It is not perfect and not the best diet. But curious as to what ratio (by weight of course) would make the combination "sufficient". I will just accept that what is obvious to me is not obvious to others. But I also know for a fact I am not alone in this curiosity.

1:0 ... you just created another universe. I'm dead.

I posit there is no answer to this as the ideal ratios of amino acids as compared to USDA recommended daily intake values (WHO has different recommendations) leads to lentils and rice both being "deficient" in Lycine and Methionine.

https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/172421/nutrients https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/168930/nutrients https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_amino_acid - these lead to ratios of roughly 18% and 9% and both lentils and rice have double digit negative ratios of these as compared to the ideal ratios from the daily recommended intake.

There is no answer to this question. This was a bad question.
USDA Link 1
USDA Link 2
Wikipedia: Essential amino acid
These lead to ratios of roughly 18% and 9% and both lentils and rice have double digit negative ratios of these as compared to the ideal ratios from the daily recommended intake.

Nah the other article is wrong as well. There is no answer because it does not make a "complete" protein. I can provide people with the math based on the Nutritional data and the USDA recommended intake if anyone is intertested. This forum is not a good medium for it.
